# json schema - Parent array(array of object) items have an inner array (array of primitive) with given values

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Please feel free to update fitting title for this question.

I am trying to achieve something like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141845/json-schema-how-to-check-that-an-array-contains-at-least-one-object-with-a-prop). An input JSON/data JSON must have an OWNER and a CHARGE_TO Account, but these don't have to be on the same Account (I.e. one Account can be OWNER, another can be CHARGE_TO) and must not contain account with any other roles.

**NOTE:** Need to define JSON schema which should be simple to maintain. i.e. Should be easy to add a new role in the condition. My valid and invalid JSONs are,

```
*************************** VALID JSON1 *********************************
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "roles": ["OWNER"]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "roles": ["ANY_OTHER_ROLE"]
    },
    {
      "name": "user3",
      "roles": ["CHARGE_TO"]
    }]  
}
*************************** VALID JSON2 *********************************
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "roles": ["OWNER", "CHARGE_TO"]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "roles": ["ANY_OTHER_ROLE"]
    }]  
}
*************************** INVALID JSON *********************************
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "roles": ["OWNER"]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "roles": ["ANY_OTHER_ROLE"]
    }]  
}
```

A JSON is valid if it has a user with roles (*"OWNER" & "CHARGE_TO"*) or if users with roles (*user1 - "OWNER", user3-"CHARGE_TO", other users with any other role*).

Below is JSON schema I tried (draft_07). **THIS IS NOT A WORKING SCHEMA**.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Complex inner array",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "type": "array",
      "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "string" },
          "orderRoles": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": { "type": "string" }
          }
        },
        "oneOf": [
          { "properties": { "roles": { "enum": ["OWNER", "CHARGE_TO"] }}},
          { "properties": { "roles": { "enum": ["OWNER"] }}},
          { "properties": { "roles": { "enum": ["CHARGE_TO"] }}}
        ]
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "string" },
          "orderRoles": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": { "type": "string" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Chaning your use of `enum` to `const` will get you part of the way there. enum is for a specific value, not a specific value IN an array. I also suggest you try using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to help you fix your schema. A good way to debug is to replace subschemas with `false` to see if the path is evaluated or not. If you still have issues after trying some more, let me know, and I may be able to help.

Comment: It's quite difficult to work out what you are asking. Rather than linking to another question and saying "like this", explain your requirements here, and explain your rules, and what you expect to happen that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Relequestual - I updated the question to explain more about my scenario. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my working schema. This is not an elegant solution as schema becomes huge if a new role ("ADMIN") is added, i.e. schema condition would `An input JSON/data JSON must have an OWNER, ADMIN and a CHARGE_TO Account, but these don't have to be on the same Account (I.e. one Account can be OWNER, one Account can be ADMIN & another can be CHARGE_TO) and must not contain account with any other roles`. Please feel free to improve this. Thanks.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Complex inner array",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "account": {
          "type": "array",
          "contains": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "roles": {
                "type": "array",
                "minItems": 1,
                "contains": { "enum": ["OWNER"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "account": {
          "type": "array",
          "contains": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "roles": {
                "type": "array",
                "minItems": 1,
                "contains": { "enum": ["CHARGE_TO"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "account": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "roles": {
                "type": "array",
                "minItems": 1,
                "items":{
                  "enum": ["CHARGE_TO", "OWNER"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate the part of the schema that checks for a specific role. Then you can just combine them with `allOf`. There's as little duplication as possible and you can easily add another constraint.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "string" },
          "roles": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" }
          }
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/require-role-owner" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/require-role-charge-to" }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "require-role-owner": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "roles": {
            "contains": { "const": "OWNER" },
            "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/not-other-role" }]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "require-role-charge-to": {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "roles": {
            "contains": { "const": "CHARGE_TO" },
            "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/not-other-role" }]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "not-other-role": {
      "items": { "enum": ["OWNER", "CHARGE_TO"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Done something similar in the answer I posted. But what you have posted doesn't meet my requirement. Ex: validation should fail for this as there is a new role in the array, but instead it passed. `{
  "user": [{
      "name": "user1",
      "roles": ["OWNER", "CHARGE_TO", "ANY_OTHER_ROLE"]
    }]  
}`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "must not contain account with any other roles" requirement. I've updated the answer to take that into account.